# Couchbase console - aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, couchbase

I used this tutorial:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/install/rhel-suse-install-intro.html#installing-using-code-class-cmd-yum-code

To install counchbase community on a aws ec2 instance…running:

```
sudo service couchbase-server start
```

I can see [OK] but when I try to accesso to my_ip:8091 I get:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

…if I try to run: `couchbase soft nproc 4096`
I get:

> couchbase: command not found

On my iptables I allow everything and also on aws networking I allowed all connections…what I’m doing wrong?

many thanks
Francesco

Comment: Try `/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase soft nproc 4096`

Comment: nothing....anyway I'm sorry I've added this: `couchbase soft nproc 4096` inside: limits.d

Comment: There are various ways to see if CB Server is running.  If you do netstat -an | grep 8091, do you see something listening on that port?  Also, which distro of Linux are you using?  If it's CentOS or RHEL v7 or later, you need `sudo systemctl start couchbase-server`, not `service`.